# Why is VirtualBox-Linux-VM slow on macos Monterey?

Tags: macos, virtualbox

I have a Ubuntu-Linux-VM running on my MacBookPro and everything is sluggish to a point it's unusable from the GUI of the VM. There is even a latency while typing.
I have the guest-additions installed.
I had a similar setup running on a much weaker mac and the GUI was

Any Idea what part of my config is the problem?

### Setup Details

- Virtual Box 6.1
- Host OS: macos Monterey 12.3
- Host RAM: 32 GB
- Host CPU: 8-Core Intel Core i9

The VM has the following resources allocated to it, following VirtualBox Manager views structure so it's easy to compare:
**System**

- Base Memory: 5120 MB RAM
- Processors: 1
- Boot Order: Hard Disk
- Acceleration: VT-x/AMD-v, Nestedf Paging, PAE/NX, KVM Paravirtualisation

**Display**

- Video Memory: 128MB
- Scale-factor: 2.00
- Graphics COntroller: VMSVGA
- Acceleration: 3D
- Remote Desktop Server: Disabled
- Recording: Disabled

Comment: What does activity monitor show?> How much RAM do you have?

Comment: VB is known as the slowest of the VMs. VMWare is faster & there's a personal use version for free. Parallels is fastest, but not cheap.

Comment: I am not doing anything performance-hungry. This has to be a configuration problem. I know for a fact that VB can run Linux in an acceptable fashion.

Comment: Did you insert the Guest Additions CD image and install the software?

Comment: Yes, sure did .

Comment: And the VirtualBox Extension Pack on the host Mac?

Comment: I did not, but I will try it out. thanks

Comment: I installed it but it had no impact on my performance bottleneck. According to the BOM in [VirtualBox's manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#intro-installing), which one do you think is relevant for performance?

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, Ubuntu (kubuntu, xubuntu) graphics is super slow, even you can see how windows are repainted, and it happens on MacBookPro2021 (i7-9750H, Radeon Pro 5300M, 32GB RAM).  On Windows system (host) with lower configuration (i7-10510), everything works quite smooth.

Comment: I've tried rockylinux 8 and have similar problems. I work around this problem by using the systems headless.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be the setting **Scale Factor** under

VirtualBox 'Settings' -> 'Display' which was set to 200%.

Setting it to 100% wil shrink whats shown on the VM-Display to the native Retina-Display resolution, but everything gets faster.
Ubuntus GUI can deal with High DPI displays, just log in to your VM and right click on the desktop and open **Display Settings**.
When you change the resolution to a big enough number (in my case 3484x2092) a setting called 'Scale' will become visible. Choose 200% and you will get the same scaling result when choosing 200% in VB. Only this time the performance is much better. Maybe only this way the 3D acceleration kicks in.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, Ubuntu (kubuntu, xubuntu) graphics is super slow, even you can see how windows are repainted, and it happens on MacBookPro2021 (i7-9750H, Radeon Pro 5300M, 32GB RAM). On Windows system (host) with lower configuration (i7-10510), everything works quite smooth.

no, changing scale factor doesn't improve/change anything.